# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet

Tags: eclipse, spring-mvc, servlets, classnotfoundexception

I have inserted all the required jars in the library of java build path and also in lib folder..
when I am trying to run the code it show me java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app
   PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
   "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>
    
    <servlet>
       <servlet-name>frontcontroller</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    
    <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>frontcontroller</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>*.*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

[image: but this error is coming]

Answer (score 0):

Go to  properties --> Deployment Assemmbly --> Add --> java build path Entries -->put all your jars here and apply